# JAX-RS 404 Not Found ExceptionMapper

Tags: java, rest, exception, jax-rs

I'm looking for way to present custom error pages if no matching JAX-RS resource was found. My idea was to use an `ExceptionMapper`, but I don't know the exception class to use:

```
@Provider
public class NotFoundMapper implements ExceptionMapper<WHATEXCEPTION?> {
  ...
}
```

RestEasy has a proprietary `NotFoundException`, but is there a way that works with Jersey, too? Ideally a standard compliant way?

Comment: Jersey implements its own [`NotFoundException`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/1.5/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/NotFoundException.html)

Comment: I'm playing with Jersey 2.0 (milestone) and can find a [`NotFoundException`](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/snapshot/jersey/javax/ws/rs/NotFoundException.html) only on the client side. Do you know what exception Jersey 2.0 uses if a resource is not found?

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with Jersey 2.0. In my Jersey 1.8 app, I throw `com.sun.jersey.api.NotFoundException`, it's also possible to use `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException`, you can pass an exception and a  `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` instance to its constructor. Jersey should figure things out if you build the `Response` to have a 404 status.

Comment: The problem is not the correct status, since Jersey returns a 404 error code, if a requested resource is not found. But I want to handle this error code to return a custom error page (instead of the default blank page).

Comment: In this case, you can just define an error page in your `web.xml`. `<error-page><error-code>404</error-code><location>path-to-jsp</location></error-page>`. It's a very simple solution. If you don't like it, the builder for `Response` allows you to pass a `Viewable` instance as the entity. The `Viewable` constructor takes a POJO and a name of a JSP.

Comment: But that would bind my code to the Servlet API. I'm using Grizzly and no servlet stuff (so far).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19169/discussion-between-tom-and-deamon)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean if your rest service is listening under localhost/rest then localhost/rest/asdf should return you a customized 404 page? It is specific to the JAX-RS engine, you must check the source code of Jersey. For example CXF throws a WebApplicationException, but it does not provide any way to customize it. See JAXRSInInterceptor.processRequest() line 156 to see how it is done :

```
    org.apache.cxf.common.i18n.Message errorMsg = 
        new org.apache.cxf.common.i18n.Message("NO_ROOT_EXC", 
                                           BUNDLE,
                                           message.get(Message.REQUEST_URI),
                                           rawPath);
    LOG.warning(errorMsg.toString());
    Response resp = JAXRSUtils.createResponse(resource, message, errorMsg.toString(), 
            Response.Status.NOT_FOUND.getStatusCode(), false);
    throw new WebApplicationException(resp);
```

To summarize there is no nice and standard way, you can try to use a request filter or an ExceptionMapper

Comment: What I mean is that the framework signals that a resource was not found and I want to handle this (exception). I don't want to throw my own exception, I want to get the exception thrown by the framework.

Comment: oh I see. so you mean if your rest service is listening under http://localhost/rest then http://localhost/rest/asdf should return you a customized 404 page? It is specific to the JAX-RS engine, you must check the source code of Jersey. For example in CXF a WebApplicationException is thrown in that case. It is a standard javax exception maybe other engines throw the same exception. In cxf you can check the JAXRSInInterceptor processRequest line 156 to see how it is handled. To summarize there is no nice and standard way, you can try to use a request filter or an ExceptionMapper

Comment: Thank you. If you replace your answer with your comment, a I will accept it as solution.